Blazor web app, The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure: RemoteCertificateNameMismatch
I deployed my Blazor web app with InteractiveWebassembly render mode with the default prerendering and also Static ssr pages to local IIS, with creating a website and setting its certificate to "IIS Express Development Certificate", after deploy, when I want to invoke a method in an api controller (probably in prerendering sincce the error occures when the page loads first or I navigate from static ssr to interactive webassembly), I get above error. I deployed this app to: https://wapps host address with the default ssl port. and in visual studio the https port is: 44302:
Server Program.cs
if (builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:44302") });//localhost:44302

if (builder.Environment.IsProduction())
{
    builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
    {
        options.AddDefaultPolicy(builder =>
        {
            builder.WithOrigins("https://wapp") 
              .AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
        });
    });
    builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://wapp") });
}

Client Program.cs
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });

I ran:
dotnet dev-certs https --trust

that said: Successfully trusted the existing HTTPS certificate.
private WeatherForecast[]? forecasts;

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    forecasts = await client.GetFromJsonAsync<WeatherForecast[]>("api/Values/WeatherForecast");
}

